# CodeMirror - Format HTML self-closing tags?

Tags: html, xml, codemirror

When I use a tag that doesn't need a closing tag(ex.label, col, input, . . .), it looks like an error.

like this:

[image]
What more configuration do I need to make the tag look pretty without a closing tag?
Option setting is as follows:

```
var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(options.target, {
   mode : 'xml',
   matchClosing: false,
   theme: options.theme || 'default',
   readOnly: options.readOnly,
   lineNumbers: options.lineNumbers,
   extraKeys: {"Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete"}
});
```

Comment: try including the `htmlmixed.js` file and set your mode as `htmlmixed`

Comment: Aha `htmlmixed` mode requires both `xml.js` file and `htmlmixed.js` file. Thanks for the hint :)